# Difference between views handler and views plugin?

Tags: 7, views

What are the main differences between view handlers and view plugins?

I checked the documentations for [view handlers](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/group/views_handlers/7) and [view plugins](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/group/views_plugins/7), but I find them quite similar.

Can anyone show me what a view handler can do that a view plugin cannot?

Answer (score 6):

The difference is summarized in the first sentence on [About Views plugins](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/group/views_plugins/7):

> In Views, a plugin is a bit like a handler, but plugins are not directly responsible for building the query. Instead, they are objects that are used to display the view or make other modifications.

A view handler is implemented using a class derived from the [views_handler](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/includes!handlers.inc/class/views_handler/7) class, which has methods to build the query, or to alter the result obtained from a query, such as:

- [views_handler::get_join()](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/includes!handlers.inc/function/views_handler%3a%3aget_join/7)
- [views_handler::pre_query()](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/includes!handlers.inc/function/views_handler%3a%3apre_query/7)
- [views_handler::sanitize_output()](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/includes!handlers.inc/function/views_handler%3a%3asanitize_value/7)
- [views_handler::post_execute()](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/includes!handlers.inc/function/views_handler%3a%3apost_execute/7)
- [views_handler::placeholder()](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/includes!handlers.inc/function/views_handler%3a%3aplaceholder/7)

On the other hand, the [views_plugin](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/includes!plugins.inc/class/views_plugin/7) class has only a method that is related to the query: [views_plugin::query()](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/includes!plugins.inc/function/views_plugin%3a%3aquery/7).